# Array result are correct within while loop, but broken outside of it

Tags: c, arrays

I'm currently writing a program that is doing what is a simple task; read a file line by line, parse it, and store the results into an array where the structure would be array[lineNumber][lineElement]. And for the most part, it's working, except for one odd issue that I've ran into.

In the code below, any access to the array that is housing the data outside of the while loop that's populating it, only returns the last entry. This occurs regardless of the key for lineNumber. Basically it acts like it's overwriting, even though within the while loop its accessible just fine. The only two items that I think could be at fault I've outlined in bold, although for **char *processData[100];**, it shouldn't be an issue as it's stored within an array that's declared outside the while loop (and if I remember right while loops shouldn't have scope?), and the other line **char **processArray[100];
**, it might be the double star for an array of pointers, but returning that to just one star introduces a whole wave of bugs, namely the aforementioned array structure breaks completely.

So in a nutshell, not being a C expert by any means and exhausting my resources for this issue, I wonder if the C coders here might have some advice as to what the heck is going on, and how I can get this to work as intended....if I even can.

As mentioned previously, the code.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    FILE *ifp;
    char line[80];
    int returnValue = 0;

    //Open file
    ifp = fopen("dataFile", "rt");

    if (ifp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file!\n");
        returnValue = 1;
    }

    int lineCounter = 0;
    char **processArray[100];

    while(fgets(line, 80, ifp) != NULL) {

        char *processData[100];

        char *p = strtok(line, " ,\n");

        int keyCounter = 0;

        while (p != NULL) {
            processData[keyCounter] = p;
            p = strtok(NULL, " ,\n");

            keyCounter++;
        }

        processArray[lineCounter] = processData;

        printf("%d\n", lineCounter);
        printf("Inside -> %s\n", processArray[0][0]);
        lineCounter++;
    }
    printf("Outside %s\n", processArray[0][0]);
    fclose(ifp);

    int i;
    int j;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            printf("%d-%d  => %s\n ", i, j,  processArray[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Each time through the outer loop, you read a new line into your `line[]` array, overwriting what was there before.  But the previous line's set of pointers still point into that array.  You're probably going to want to call `malloc` to allocate a fresh array for each line of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Just about] everything gets overwritten on the outer `while` loop, so only the last processed line remains. The intermediate results must be preserved

I've fixed the program with annotations as to the bugs. The style is `#if 0 /* original code */ #else /* fixed code */ #endif`

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(void)
{
    FILE *ifp;
    char line[80];
    int returnValue = 0;

    //Open file
    ifp = fopen("dataFile", "rt");

    if (ifp == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file!\n");
            returnValue = 1;
    }

    int lineCounter = 0;
    char **processArray[100];

    // NOTE/BUG: things get lost on each iteration of this loop
    while(fgets(line, 80, ifp) != NULL) {
            char *processData[100];

            char *p = strtok(line, " ,\n");

            int keyCounter = 0;

            while (p != NULL) {
            // NOTE/BUG: p will get overwritten -- so we must save the string
#if 0
                    processData[keyCounter] = p;
#else
                    processData[keyCounter] = strdup(p);
#endif
                    p = strtok(NULL, " ,\n");

                    keyCounter++;
            }

            // NOTE/BUG: processData must be duplicated -- it is overwritten
            // on the outer loop
#if 0
            processArray[lineCounter] = processData;
#else
            char **pA = malloc(sizeof(char *) * keyCounter);
            processArray[lineCounter] = pA;
            for (int copyidx = 0;  copyidx < keyCounter;  ++copyidx)
                pA[copyidx] = processData[copyidx];
#endif

            printf("%d\n", lineCounter);
            printf("Inside -> %s\n", processArray[0][0]);
            lineCounter++;
    }
    printf("Outside %s\n", processArray[0][0]);
    fclose(ifp);

    int i;
    int j;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    printf("%d-%d  => %s\n ", i, j,  processArray[i][j]);
            }
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: That worked as expected thanks. Also thanks for explaining why it's occurring, and for showing what it should be instead of what it was in the code itself. As a visual learner, it makes things easier. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for the feedback on the `#if 0` thing. I've started to do that [where possible] more and more. Your code was in good enough shape already that I could combine the `NOTE/BUG` _and_ the fix in the same place. For some questions, I [have to] annotate the bugs in one code block and provide the fix in another because the code needs a lot more restructuring than yours did.

Answer (score 1):

`processData` is being allocated on the stack and the memory address is not valid after you leave the while loop, regardless of you storing it in processArray.  You need to allocate from the heap instead (using malloc or some other memory allocation function)

Comment: That does make sense when explained out like that thanks. As someone that is used to working with languages that handle memory management for me, getting my head around stack and heap seems to always throw me for a loop. Thanks for your reply.